# How to navigate back to login page using Ionic V2 this.nav.setRoot

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having trouble with navigation back to my login screen using Ionic V2.

I'm using the V2 tabs template and added a login page myself and set `rootPage = LoginPage;` in `app.components.ts`

If the login promise is returned I set `this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage)` in `login.ts` and everything is still working fine.

The problem arises when I logout, I set `this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage)` in `home.ts` and the App redirects to the login page, however the tabs on the bottom are still visible.

How do I re-initialize the login screen without the tabs after logging out?

Answer (score 9):

You need remove `Tab` from nav.

```
import { App  } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(public app: App ) {}
signout(){
  this.app.getRootNav().setRoot( LoginPage );
}
```

Comment: @LouwrensJacobusLabuschagne accept  it as answer so that it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Demo{
   tabBarElement: any; 

   constructor(){
       this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');}

   ionViewDidLoad() {
       this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';}
}
```

> "It's working for me"